# GWT Tree, opening event

Tags: gwt, treeview, tree

I'm using the tree control in GWT. I have a custom widget that I add as a TreeItem:

```
Tree testTree = new Tree();
testTree.addItem(myWidget);
```

I would like to retrieve myWidget instance on the node opening event. Is it possible ? Does anybody knows which event should I be using ?

*I tried the `openHandler<TreeItem>` but what I retrieve is the... tree item.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking to far.

To answer my original question:
The event we retrieve in the openHandler has all the info I needed.

```
public void onOpen(OpenEvent<TreeItem> event) {
// The TreeItem
TreeItem ti = event.getTarget();

// The widget added in the treeItem
CustomWidget cw = (CustomWidget)event.getTarget().getWidget();
}
```

Just for info:

Instead of adding a widget (which I didn't use anywhere else) to my TreeItem I extended TreeItem to create my own Widget. So I simply needed `event.getTarget()` to access it.

About FastTree:

For what I read people working with GWT usually go straight to using [FastTree](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/FastTree) which, as Jason said, offers more possibilities and better performances. 
I had problem running FastTree in my configuration (even with the examples code) and little time to deal with it so that's why I sticked with the native Tree widget.

Answer (score 2):

In almost every case in which you're using GWT's `Tree`, you really want to be using the GWT Incubator's [`FastTree`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/FastTree), which has an [`addBeforeOpenHandler()`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#kxqvj77bOTo/trunk/src/com/google/gwt/gen2/complexpanel/client/FastTree.java&q=addbeforeopenhandler%20package:http://google-web-toolkit-incubator%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) method, which takes a `BeforeOpenHandler<FastTreeItem>` which passes a `BeforeOpenEvent` to `onBeforeOpen()` making available the `source` of the event (that was a mouthful...)

Long story short, `FastTree` > `Tree`, and you want to use `addBeforeOpenHandler()` on the `FastTree` itself.

To add widgets to your tree (instead of just `FastTreeItem`s) you can add your widget to the enclosing `FastTreeItem`, or just subclass `FastTreeItem` to do what you want.